# Android Studio 2.2.3 - Is there a shorcut/hotkey to do zoom in/out into the blueprint screen?

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

I'm looking to find or set a shortcut to do zoom in/out into the blueprint window instead of clicking with mouse buttons. How can I do that?

[image: Android Studio, blueprint window zoom detail]

Comment: ctrl + scrollwheel?

Comment: @Hafnernuss Tried that before and doesn't work.

Comment: i know its only for the editor but maybe?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/zooming-in-the-editor.html

Comment: @Hafnernuss Only works in text editor :/

Comment: then im out of ideas, sorry. Seems like the classic IntelliJ experience. unintuitive and clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

The hand icon near to + icon have feature "pan and zoom" click that icon and pinch the touch pad. I guess here is no other shortcut.